# Does 'Google Safe Browsing' send a request on each opened url or use a cached list?

Tags: privacy, google-chrome, tracking

[google safe browsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Safe_Browsing) is the feature that show you this alert on malicious web sites:

[image]

My question is: is there a request to the API on each opened URL, or the browser use a cache ?

If you open `about:config` in firefox, and search `safebrowsing`, you have tons of (possibly interesting) entrys.

Some [explanations on how it works](https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/how-safe-browsing-works-in-firefox/)

A [post on reddit on the same topic](https://www.reddit.com/r/privacytoolsIO/comments/7n0s5r/google_safebrowsing_options_in_firefox_config/)

from [@MrTimscampi](https://www.reddit.com/user/MrTimscampi/):

> Do note that the SafeBrowsing lists are LOCAL. Your history never
>   touches Google servers. It basically downloads a blocklist, like
>   AdBlock/Ublock then does the blocking locally. I'd leave it on, as
>   it's a layer of protection and no data is ever sent to Google.

We can check that we have local cache (Linux), but all files are binary data, not plain text :

```
cd ~/.cache/mozilla/firefox/
cd $(ls -t | sed q)/safebrowsing
ls
ads-track-digest256.pset                     block-flashsubdoc-digest256.sbstore   social-track-digest256.sbstore
ads-track-digest256.sbstore                  content-track-digest256.pset          test-block-simple.pset
allow-flashallow-digest256.pset              content-track-digest256.sbstore       test-block-simple.sbstore
allow-flashallow-digest256.sbstore           except-flash-digest256.pset           test-harmful-simple.pset
analytics-track-digest256.pset               except-flash-digest256.sbstore        test-harmful-simple.sbstore
analytics-track-digest256.sbstore            except-flashallow-digest256.pset      test-malware-simple.pset
base-cryptomining-track-digest256.pset       except-flashallow-digest256.sbstore   test-malware-simple.sbstore
base-cryptomining-track-digest256.sbstore    except-flashsubdoc-digest256.pset     test-phish-simple.pset
base-fingerprinting-track-digest256.pset     except-flashsubdoc-digest256.sbstore  test-phish-simple.sbstore
base-fingerprinting-track-digest256.sbstore  google4/                              test-track-simple.pset
base-track-digest256.pset                    mozplugin-block-digest256.pset        test-track-simple.sbstore
base-track-digest256.sbstore                 mozplugin-block-digest256.sbstore     test-trackwhite-simple.pset
block-flash-digest256.pset                   mozstd-trackwhite-digest256.pset      test-trackwhite-simple.sbstore
block-flash-digest256.sbstore                mozstd-trackwhite-digest256.sbstore   test-unwanted-simple.pset
block-flashsubdoc-digest256.pset             social-track-digest256.pset           test-unwanted-simple.sbstore
```

Another interesting internal ressoure: `chrome://browser/content/browser-safebrowsing.js`

**Better have more advises on this feature please**

Comment: Welcome. Questions about technologies as well web browsers are off-topic on this site, by the other hand "Google Safe Browsing" is not a web application as it's defined on [help/on-topic]. I suggest you to ask in [meta.se] if there is a site on [se] where you could ask this question.